# matrix rotation..for loop changes the value of pointer

Tags: c

In the final value of array only first element becomes zero and that too when it again goes to the for loop(checked using gdb)..i have mentioned the problem using comments at the bottom of code.Help me out.. I have no clue of what is going wrong.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    int main()
    {
        int a, b, c;
        printf("enter the size of matrix");
        scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
        printf("enter the number of rotations");
        scanf("%d",&c);
        int *arr = malloc (sizeof(int) * a * b);

        int x = (a >= b)? a : b;
        printf("enter the values of matrix");
        // scanning the values

        for(int i = 0; i < a; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < b; j++)
            {
                scanf("%d",(arr + i * b + j));
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

        // main code starts

        for(int y = 0; y < c; y++)
        {
            // declared a new array

            int *arr1 = malloc (sizeof(int) * a * b);
            for(int k = 0; k < x / 2; k++)
            {
                for(int i = k; i < a - k; i++)
                {
                    for(int j = k; j < b - k; j++)
                    {
                        if (i == k && j > k)
                        {
                            *(arr1 + i * b + j - 1) = *(arr + i * b + j);

                        }

                        else if (i == a - k - 1 && j < b - k - 1)
                        {
                            *(arr1 + i * b + j + 1) = *(arr + i * b + j); 

                        } 

                        else if (j == k && i < a - k - 1)
                        {
                            *(arr1 + i * b + j + b) = *(arr + i * b + j);

                        }

                        else if (j == b - k - 1 && i > k)
                        {
                            *(arr1 + i * b + j - b) = *(arr + i * b + j); 

                        }
                    }
                }
                if (x % 2 != 0 && a == b)
                *(arr1 + x / 2 * b + (b / 2)) = *(arr + x / 2 * b + (b / 2));
            }

            // changing the old array to new array


            arr = arr1;
            // first value is getting printed correctly here
            printf("%d\n",*(arr));
            printf("%p\n",&(*arr));
            free(arr1);


        }

        // printing the output
        for(int i = 0; i < a; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < b; j++)
            {
                printf("%d ",*(arr + i * b + j));
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

        // first value is getting printed incorrectly here, outside the loop
            printf("\n%d\n",*(arr));
            printf("%p",&(*arr));

    }
```

Comment: A description of what the code is supposed to achieve would be helpful ("matrix rotation" could mean many different things).  Sample input and expected vs. observed output would be very valuable.  An explanation of how the algorithm is intended to work, either in code comments or in prose, would be nice, too.

Comment: As Jonathan has said, C doesn't support array assignment. But that's not really the issue. You're not assigning arrays. You're assigning pointers. That only copies the address of the allocated memory, not the data that you've since stored there.

Comment: rotation in anti-clockwise direction such that a[0][0] becomes a[1][0] , a[0][1] becomes a[0][0] and so on @JohnBollinger

Comment: m assigning the address that  arr1 is storing to arr ..And because it has access to the all the values using address of array, it must easily print the values ..The values are same , the address is same , just the pointer which is storing it has now a different name ..so, i dont think there is anything wrong in that ..@underscore_d

Answer (score 0):

C doesn't support array assignment.  You have:

```
    int *arr = malloc (sizeof(int) * a * b);
    …
        int *arr1 = malloc (sizeof(int) * a * b);
        …
        arr = arr1;
        …
        free(arr1);
```

The assignment  means you've lost your original array (memory leak) and you then invalidate your new array with the `free()`.

Array copying requires more code — usually a function call such as `memmove()` or `memcpy()`, possibly wrapped in a function.

For example, add `#include <string.h>` and use this in place of the `arr = arr1;` assignment:

```
    memmove(arr, arr1, sizeof(int) * a * b);
    free(arr1);   // No longer needed
```

Alternatively:

```
    free(arr);
    arr = arr1;
```

This code runs cleanly under [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) on Mac OS X 10.11.5 with GCC 6.1.0 with the 'Either' or the 'Or' options for handling the array assignments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static void dump_matrix(const char *tag, int *arr, int a, int b)
{
    printf("Matrix: %s\n", tag);
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
            printf(" %3d", arr[i * b + j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int a, b, c;
    printf("enter the size of matrix: ");
    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
    printf("enter the number of rotations: ");
    scanf("%d", &c);
    int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * a * b);

    int x = (a >= b) ? a : b;
    printf("enter the values of matrix: ");
    // scanning the values

    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
        {
            if (scanf("%d", (arr + i * b + j)) != 1)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "failed to read value arr[%d][%d]\n", i, j);
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    dump_matrix("Initial input", arr, a, b);

    // main code starts

    for (int y = 0; y < c; y++)
    {
        // declared a new array
        int *arr1 = malloc(sizeof(int) * a * b);
        for (int k = 0; k < x / 2; k++)
        {
            for (int i = k; i < a - k; i++)
            {
                for (int j = k; j < b - k; j++)
                {
                    if (i == k && j > k)
                    {
                        *(arr1 + i * b + j - 1) = *(arr + i * b + j);
                    }
                    else if (i == a - k - 1 && j < b - k - 1)
                    {
                        *(arr1 + i * b + j + 1) = *(arr + i * b + j);
                    }
                    else if (j == k && i < a - k - 1)
                    {
                        *(arr1 + i * b + j + b) = *(arr + i * b + j);
                    }
                    else if (j == b - k - 1 && i > k)
                    {
                        *(arr1 + i * b + j - b) = *(arr + i * b + j);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (x % 2 != 0 && a == b)
                *(arr1 + x / 2 * b + (b / 2)) = *(arr + x / 2 * b + (b / 2));
        }

        // Changing the old array to new array
        // Either:
        // memmove(arr, arr1, sizeof(int) * a * b);
        // free(arr1);
        // Or:
        free(arr);
        arr = arr1;

        dump_matrix("After rotation", arr, a, b);
    }

    dump_matrix("Finished", arr, a, b);

    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Note the use of the `dump_matrix()` function.  Writing such a function once means it can be used multiple places in the code.  The `tag` argument simplifies the use.  The 'commercial grade' variant takes a `FILE *fp` argument too and writes to the specified file stream.

Note the error checking on the main input loop `scanf()`.  I should also have checked the two other `scanf()` statements.  Errors are reported on standard error, of course.

Example run:

```
$ ./mat31
enter the size of matrix: 3 4
enter the number of rotations: 2
enter the values of matrix: 1 2 3 4 10 11 12 13 99 98 97 96



Matrix: Initial input
   1   2   3   4
  10  11  12  13
  99  98  97  96
Matrix: After rotation
   2   3   4  13
   1  12  11  96
  10  99  98  97
Matrix: After rotation
   3   4  13  96
   2  11  12  97
   1  10  99  98
Matrix: Finished
   3   4  13  96
   2  11  12  97
   1  10  99  98
$
```

Whether the output is what you intended is a wholly separate discussion.  This is simply not abusing the memory.

Comment: m assigning addresses of arrays rather than array itself..arr and arr1 are two pointers which are storing the addresses of two different arrays and m just making arr point to the same array as that of arr1 @Jonathan Leffler

Comment: OK.  You can do that — indeed, the code shown is working with the two pointers and switching the assignment.  You have to track and free the memory originally allocated to `arr` before you change it to point to where `arr1` points to — otherwise, you leak the memory originally allocated to `arr`.  And, at the end, you need to free the memory `arr` points to. It isn't actually crucial if you're about to exit the program, but it is good to release the allocated memory where it is simple to do so, as it is in this code. With C, you must track all allocated memory and know which code will free it.

Comment: What you can't do safely, but the code in the question does it anyway, is copy the value of the pointer `arr1` over the pointer `arr`, then free `arr1`, and then reference the array again.  Once the array is freed, whether it's freed via the name `arr` or `arr1`, any further access to the data is invalid — undefined behaviour — whether it's accessed via the name `arr` or `arr1`.